# How to rotate a Vector3 of dimensions by a Vector3 of angles?

Tags: c#, math, vector

I have a Vector 3 of how many blocks in a grid a piece is along each axis. For example if one of these vectors was ( 1, 2, 1 ) it would be 1 block long on the x-axis, 2 blocks long on the y-axis, and one block long on the z-axis. I also have a Vector 3 of angles that denote rotations along each axis. For example if one of these vectors was ( 90, 180, 0 ) the piece would be rotated by 90 degrees around the x-axis, 180 degrees around the y-axis, and 0 degrees around the z-axis. What I can't figure out is how to rotate the dimensions of a piece by its vector of rotation angles so i know what points in space its occupying.

```cs
public class Block
{
    private Vector3 localOrientation;
    private Vector3 dimensions;

    public Vector3 GetRotatedDimensions()
    {
         //your implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your y rotation based on the initial alignment or the alignment AFTER the x rotation?

Comment: The rotations you're specifying look like Euler angles. These need to be applied in a specific order. If you're only worried about rotations that are multiples of 90 degrees, the answer is a lot simpler. Are you interested in arbitrary rotations?

Answer (score 0):

<s>If I understand correctly, there is something fundamentally wrong with your question. There can be no "rotated dimensions". Let's use a rectangle to demonstrate this.</s> (I didn't undestand correctly)

Suppose there's this initial rectangle:

[image: Initial rectangle]

and you rotate it. This is what you get:

[image: Rectangle after rotation]

Using a single Vector2, you can't differentiate a "rotated x*y rectangle" from a "initial (x')*(y') rectangle". To sufficiently describe the position of a rectangle, you need to keep the size AND the rotation in your block-describing variable.

Is `x'` and `y'` what you wanted to know? <s>I doubt it.</s> Oh, you do? Great!

In 3 dimensions, I would define what you're looking for as

```
The minimum dimensions of a rectangular box that
1. has its faces parallel to the XY, XZ and YZ planes and
2. contains another rectangular box of known dimensions and orientation.
```

There are possibly more elegant solutions, but I'd brute force it like this:

1. Make 8 Vector3 objects (one for each vertex of your block),
2. Rotate all of them around the x-axis.
3. Rotate them (the new ones you got from "2") around the y-axis.
4. Rotate them (the new ones you got from "3") around the z-axis.
5. Find the min and max values of the x, y and z coordinates among all your points.
6. Your new dimensions would be (x_max-x_min), (y_max-y_min), (z_max-z_min).

I'm not 100% sure about this though, so make sure you verify the results!

Comment: Actually x and y prime are exactly what I was looking for. Except in 3d space.

Comment: @user10003286 I added a possible solution algorithm. Take a look, maybe it does what you're looking for.

Comment: Of note is that the order you specify for rotations does not match [Unity's](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html). This might lead to some apparent discrepancies between what you see in the editor vs what you might expect to see.